# Best way to schedule daily change in CSS parameter

Tags: php, css, wp-cron, automation

I have a few CSS values on my WP site that I would like to change once a day on a daily basis using a random variable and I am trying to determine the most elegant way of doing this. For the sake of simplicity, in this example, I will attempt to automatically randomize, on a daily basis, the `padding` of a `div` with the id `variablePaddingDiv`.

I am pretty sure that I would want to use WP_cron, and using [this codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cron), I *think* I figured out how to do it, but I wanted to check it with the community. That way I can learn best practices and at the same time maybe provide an answer for someone else who may also be trying to figure out how to update CSS using a scheduled task.

### My Best Guess

I think I the best way to do this would be to 1) schedule a daily revision of some CSS and then 2) enqueue that CSS file every time I load the page.

#### Part 1: Modifying Daily a CSS file

I think this is the code I would add to my `functions.php` to run the daily update of the CSS file (i.e. part 1):

```
function change_padding_activation() {
  if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'change_padding_hook' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'change_padding_hook' );
   }
}

function change_padding_function() {

   $min = 20;  // the minimum value of padding
   $max = 40;  // the maximum value of padding
   $var_padding = rand ( $min , $max );  // pick a random number between the min and the max

   $css_string='#variablePaddingDiv { padding: ' . $var_padding . '%;}'; // write the CSS using variable created above.
   $a = fopen("my_css_file_written_with_php.css", 'w');                 // open the file
   fwrite($a, $css_string); // write to the file
   fclose($a); //close the file
   chmod("my_css_file_written_with_php.css", 0644);             // <---- also, do I need this?
}

add_action( 'wp', 'change_padding_activation' ); // hook calls the activation function
add_action( 'change_padding_hook', 'change_padding_function' ); //hook calls the function that changes the file
```

#### Part 2: Enqueuing the CSS file

Then I believe I would add this code to enqueue the updated CSS file to my `functions.php` file (part 2):

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'parentThemeName_child_enqueue_styles' );

function parentThemeName_child_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parentThemeName-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' ); //my parent theme style
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parentThemeName-child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css'  );  //my child theme style
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parentThemeName-child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/my_css_file_written_with_php.css'); // the updated CSS file from part 1 (above)
}
```

Can someone please tell me if they think that there are any problems with this approach, and if so, perhaps tell me what they are and suggest a better way to go about the task?  Thank you!